# How can I find out where an API is located?

Tags: http, curl, nslookup

I want to discover where this API is located:
https://www.manitobah.com/products.json

When i do nslookup/ip check it says it's in canada, but that's only for the host (manitobah.com, not manitobah.com/products.json)

Is there a method to find where the server responding to this request is located?

Comment: It's Cloudflare. It is impossible to get the real location of the server, or its IP address.

Comment: so no way to find where the source API is located? Would it be serving me stale/cached data potentially?

Comment: Well Cloudflare might give some indication if the data is cached, but the target server can reply with anything.